# S4 Android Emulator

Tags: android, windows, macos

I tried to create custom S4 Emulator with resolution size 1080*1920 in AVD Manager. While i starting emulator , it is not all starting just showing blank screen for 25 min . What will be the issue ? There is no possibility to create S4 emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you are limited to using 768 MB of RAM for the virtual devices you create. This creates a problem when you create a screen as big as the one you have, since it will require more RAM than that to run. If you simply try to use the normal options to create a device that big it will not run as you have seen.

The way to fix this is to use ONLY the x86 images (no it will not be a GS4 processor but it's just an emulator), and run the intel x86 emulator accelerometer (HAXM) that is all the way at the bottom of the list in the SDK Manager. Install it and during the installation it will ask if you want to allot 2 GB of your PC's RAM to the virtual device. Enable that and your device should run.

Also check "use host GPU" as stated in the other answer.

As for OSX, hopefully someone else can help.